# C++ Regular Expressions multiline replace

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I seek more knowledge of ones mind again.

I have a C++ solution which uses the Boost libraries as the solution requires to work within a Linux enviroment.  However my knowledge is within C# and C++ is a somewhat new area of mine which I've dived into.

I'm looking for an example use of how I could create a somewhat template and replace the values via regex?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  {$1}.somedomain.com
    ServerAlias {$1}
    ServerAdmin mr.admin@somedomain.com

    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /some/dir/{$2}/{$3}/{$4}
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "{$5}"
        AuthUserFile /some/dir/{$2}/{$3}/{$4}/{$4}.users
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And a key of the values:
{ Already formatted, just require to be replaced with the $n's }

```
$1 = sub domain alias (3 characters long)
$2 = is either "public" or "private"
$3 = a users username (no more than 25 characters)
$4 = the svn project name (no more than 30 characters and " " replaced with "_")
$5 = the actual repository name given by the user.
```

Ideally a function/method will be able to handle this so I can just pass say a repository object through then render it via that.

Many thanks,
Shaun

Comment: Is this almost-but-not-quite-like-XML style template your idea or an requirement? Because... it's a terrible idea.

Comment: Hello Tomalak, unfortunately it's a requirement.  I'm not that insane to come up with something as crazy as this yet.  The above is a VirtualHost for apache using the enabled mod for svn.  Cheers, Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need the power of regular expressions, you can do with find/replace.

```
void replaceall(string& source, const string& pattern, const string& replacement)
{
    int curr = 0;
    while ((curr = str.find(pattern, curr)) != string::npos)
        str.replace(curr, parrern.length(), replacement);
}

void substitutetemplate(
        const string& subDomainAlias,
        bool publicOrPrivate,
        const string& userName,
        const string& svnProjectName,
        const string& repositoryName)
{
    string result = m_template;

    replaceall(result, "{$1}", subDomainAlias);

    string pop = publicOrPrivate ? "public" : "private";
    replaceall(result, "{$2}", pop);

    replaceall(result, "{$3}", userName);

    string svnProjectNameWithoutSpaces = svnProjectName;
    replaceall(svnProjectNameWithoutSpaces, " ", "_");
    replaceall(result, "{$4}", svnProjectNameWithoutSpaces);

    replaceall(result, "{$5}", repositoryName);
    m_result = result;
}
```

`m_template` should be a big string containing the whole template with linebreaks.